# Pass null datetime parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell

So I have a powershell script that takes region and datetime as input and internally in the script it calls a stored procedure.

The stored procedure takes two inputs - region and datetimestamp; the datetimestamp is always null. How do I go about parsing it?

```
function Reset {

param ([string]$region,[nullable[Datetime]]$statustimestamp)

        $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=SQL,15010; Database='STG';User ID=SVC;Password=password;Integrated Security=FALSE")
        $conn.Open()
        $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
        $cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Reset'$region' ,'$statustimestamp'"
        $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
        $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        [void]$adapter.Fill($dataset)
        $dataset.tables[0]
        $cmd.CommandText    
        $dataset.Tables[0] | Export-CSV M:\MyReport.csv -encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation    
        Write-Host 'New report M:\MyReport.csv has been successfully generated' 
    }
```

I execute it as

```
Rest -region IN -statustimestamp NULL
```

and I get the following error

> Reset : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'statustimestamp'. Cannot convert value "NULL" to type "System.DateTime".
>   Error: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.
>   At line:1 char:59
>   + Reset -region AU -statustimestamp NULL
>   +                                                           ~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Reset], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Reset

Comment: You can just call your function without the date parameter, like `Rest -region IN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null in PowerShell is represented by `$null` and not `NULL`, that's why the error message is saying the string `NULL` cannot be converted to a (nullable) `DateTime`.

```
Rest -region IN -statustimestamp $null
```

You can also omit the `-statustimestamp` parameter altogether.

Comment: "You can also omit the -statustimestamp parameter altogether." - you could, but that would mean a slight change, namely that `$PSBoundParameters` will no longer contain an entry for `statustimestamp`

Comment: pasrsing $null or not parsing the parameter does help with execution .But its defaulting to 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM , i want to pass it the value null

Comment: I was able to surpass that by using Exec in my script

Answer (score 3):

To complement [dee-see's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58417820/45375):

Note: However your parameters are declared, `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('<parameter-name>')` inside a script/function tells you whether an argument was *explicitly passed* to a given parameter (a *default value* doesn't count); e.g., with the invocation in your question (had it succeeded), `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('statustimestamp')` would indicate `$true`.

**If you want your parameter value to be `$null` *by omission***:

Declare your parameter simply as `[Datetime] $statustimestamp` and *pass no argument to it* on invocation; `$statustimestamp` will then *implicitly* be `$null`.

```
# Declare a parameter in a script block (which works like a function)
# and invoke the script block without an argument for that parameter:
PS> & { param([Datetime] $statustimestamp) $null -eq $statustimestamp }

True  # $statustimestamp was $null
```

---

**If you want to support *explicitly passing `$null`* as an argument:**

This may be necessary if you declare a *mandatory* parameter, yet you want to allow `$null` as an explicit signal that a default value should be used.

Unfortunately, the **specifics of the parameter declaration currently depend on whether the data type of the parameter is a *reference type* (such as `[string]` or `[System.IO.FileInfo]`) or a *value type* (such as `[int]` or `[datetime]`)**.
You can inspect a given type's `.IsValueType` property to learn whether it is a value type (`$true)` or a reference type (`$false`); e.g.: `[datetime].IsValueType` yields `$true`).

If the **parameter type is a *reference type***, you can use the `[AllowNull()]` attribute:

```
PS> & { 
  param(
    [AllowNull()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.IO.FileInfo] $Foo  # System.IO.FileInfo is a *reference type*
  )
  $null -eq $Foo 
} -Foo $null

True  # $Foo was $null
```

Unfortunately, the **same technique doesn't work with *value types*** such as `[DateTime]`, so your **parameter must indeed be typed as `[Nullable[DateTime]`**, as in your question:

```
PS> & { 
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [AllowNull()] # Because the parameter is mandatory, this is *also* needed.
    [Nullable[DateTime]] $Foo  # System.DateTime is a *value type*
  )
  $null -eq $Foo 
} -Foo $null

True  # $Foo was $null
```

Note: These requirements - needing to pay attention to the difference between value types and reference types and needing to use a `[Nullable[T]]` type - are obscure and uncharacteristic for PowerShell.

**Doing away with these requirements** in favor of a unified approach (making it work for value types the way it already does for reference types) **is the 
subject of [this proposal on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10817)**.